# How do I process multiple variables in the same way?

Tags: ruby, variables

It's highly probable this question has been asked, but I can't find the answer.

I have four variables:

```ruby
a,b,c,d = [a,b,c,d].map{|myvar| myvar+1 }
```

How can I make this line more DRY (keeping it compact), i.e., achieve the same changes without repeating variable names?

Comment: A faster way to write this is: a,b,c,d = [1,2,3,4].map(&:succ)

Comment: you probably wanted to comment on doesterr's post, i dont see how it is related to mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have a growing suspicion that short answer (for this specific example with integers) is "no way"

due to the same reason as described in the answer in my previous question:

[replacing referenced Integer value in Ruby like String#replace does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139251/replacing-referenced-integer-value-in-ruby-like-stringreplace-does)

update:

if variables we operate on are an Array, Hash or String, and they keep the same datatype after the performed operation, it's drier, more compact and saving memory to use replace

```
[a,b,c,d].each{|v| v.replace(v + [1])} #example for an array
```

Comment: the answer from the other question has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: this question is about variables. i'd definitely use map! without asking a question if i would have time to rewrite everything to arrays. referred answer shows that replace cannot be used on integers. thus i cannot write for example [a,b,c,d].each{|v| v.replace(v+1)}

Answer (score 2):

Don't create separate variables, put the values in an Array or Hash from the beginning.

```
data = []
data << 1
data << 2
data << 3
data << 4
data = data.map { |value| value + 1 }
data.inspect # => [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

or

```
data = {}
data[:a] = 1
data[:b] = 2
data[:c] = 3
data[:d] = 4
data.each { |key, value| data[key] = value + 1}
data.inspect # => {:a=>2, :b=>3, :c=>4, :d=>5}
```

Comment: Or use [`map!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map-21) to avoid the reassignment.

Comment: right! wanted to keep it as similar as possible to the code from the question